Add button to Strapi v5 admin panel collection page?
I want to add a custom button on the Strapi v5 Collection Edit Page in the admin panel. My particular collection is called Resources. I want this text to display under the Publish button when adding a new Resource.
I have read the docs here and here, but it's all a bit too vague and I'm not managing to get anything working.
Nothing ever shows up in the admin panel.
Below is the example app.tsx file provided by Strapi:
import type { StrapiApp } from '@strapi/strapi/admin';

export default {
  config: {
    locales: [
      // 'ar',
      // 'fr',
      // 'cs',
    ],
  },
  bootstrap(app: StrapiApp) {
    console.log(app);
  },
};

Below is what I have tried:
import type { StrapiApp } from '@strapi/strapi/admin';
import React from 'react';

export default {
  config: {
    locales: [],
  },
  bootstrap(app: StrapiApp) {
    console.log('Bootstrapping Strapi Admin with customizations...');

    // Use the mutate-edit-view-layout hook to customize the Edit View for the Resource collection type
    app.registerHook('Admin/CM/pages/EditView/mutate-edit-view-layout', ({ layout }) => {
      if (layout.uid === 'api::resource.resource') {
        // Add a custom field or component to the layout
        layout.layout.push([
          {
            name: 'customMessage',
            size: 12, // Full-width field
            customField: () => (
              <div style={{ marginTop: '20px', color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Hello from the Custom Edit View for Resource!
              </div>
            ),
          },
        ]);
      }

      return { layout };
    });
  },
};


I have npm run build and npm run develop and still nothing appears.
I am at a loss as to how to get this to work?
Any help is so appreciated!
